# I need to reverse the 5 digit number input by the user in C. Code has no syntax error (no error squiggles) but still code doesn't run

Tags: c, logic

There might be some error in the logic used by me. Could someone please point that out to me?

```
//Reverse the number

#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int m,a,b,c,d,e,n;

    printf("\nEnter a five digit number: ");
    scanf("%d",m);

    a = m/10000;                                        //1st digit     
    b = (m - a*10000)/1000;                             //2nd digit
    c = ((m-a*10000) - b*1000)/100;                     //3rd digit
    d = (((m-a*10000) - b*1000) - c*100)/10;            //4th digit
    e = ((((m-a*10000) - b*1000) - c*100) - d*10);      //5th digit

    n = e*10000 + d*1000 + c*100 + b*10 + a;            //reverse of the number
    
    printf("Reverse of the number given by you is %d\n", n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I recommend you learn about the *modulo* operator `%`. For example, when you have your five-digit number what is the result of `m % 10000`?

Comment: Change `scanf("%d",m);` to `scanf("%d",&m);`. `scanf()` expects pointers as it's arguments.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I know that it returns the remainder. Being a complete novice, I haven't used it enough in my problems.

Comment: @JustASimpleLonelyProgrammer ohhhh thanks a lot man! 

Comment: It will help you avoid all those cumulative subtractions. As in `a = m / 10000; m %= 10000; b = m / 1000; etc...`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Could you explain how I could use modular division here?

Comment: `scanf("%d", m)` is wrong (it should be `scanf("%d", &m);`. I'm not sure what error squiggles are, but all modern compilers will warn about this by default.

Comment: @PaulHankin I use Visual studio Code. It didn't ‍♂️. Also error squiggles are those red indications of errors

Comment: read the number/input as a string and walk a pointer from end of string to begin of string, or reverse the string (swap characters with double pointers and then `sscanf` the result

Comment: Note: 'Code has no syntax error (no error squiggles) but still code doesn't run' is normal behaviour.  Debugging and testing is the next step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed out in a comment your bug is here:

```
scanf("%d",m);  -->  scanf("%d", &m);
           ^                     ^^
         wrong                  correct
```

as `scanf` must be passed a pointer to the object where the converted value is to be stored.

Your calculation can be simplified by using `%` like

```
e = m % 10;      //5th digit
m = m / 10;
d = m % 10;      //4th digit
m = m / 10;
c = m % 10;      //3rd digit
m = m / 10;
b = m % 10;      //2nd digit
m = m / 10;
a = m % 10;      //1st digit
```

As you can see the calculation is the same every time so you could use a loop.

```
int factor = 10000;
n = 0;
while(m != 0)
{
    n = n + (m % 10) * factor;
    m = m / 10;
    factor = factor / 10;
}
```

Note: The loop above only works when the input has **exactly** 5 digits. A more generic solution could be:

```
n = 0;
while(m != 0)
{
    n = n * 10;
    n = n + (m % 10);
    m = m / 10;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @4386427. I haven't studied about loops yet. Will surely try this after I do :) 